# HP pavilion g6 shutdown thermal overheating

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, shutdown, hp-pavilion

My HP pavilion g6 notebook has the following configuration:

Intel core i5 processor
6 gb RAM
1 gb dedicated ATI graphics.

It has dual boot system with windows 7 home basic 64 bit and ubuntu 11.10 64 bit installed.
 The installation process was ok. And i am facing no problem in using the ubuntu distro. But the problem that i am facing is that...whenever i am shutting down my notebook, after resuming the notebook, i am getting a message that "thermal power overheating.....". For windows 7, there is no problem during shutdown. Only for ubuntu and any other linux, it is giving the problem.

Please tell me how to get rid off this problem.

Thanks,
Biplab Banerjee

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest BIOS from [HP](http://www.hp.com/support). If the issue is not resolved by updating the BIOS, you will have to send the notebook for repair.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have solved it yet.

I installed the last version of BIOS (I download it in the hp web page). I reinstall ubuntu but I chose Install and not Try in the first window.

I don't know what of the two things I have done has solved the problem but now it works fine. The only problem I have is that when I start ubuntu the screen darken, I must light it every time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same notebook and had the same problem after I installed Peppermint, Mint, Ubuntu 11.10, Ubuntu 11.04, OpenSuSE, and some other Linux distros. Finally, I found the solution. Here's how I did it:

the long term support is the solution 10.04 and is run perfect without problems

1. Update your BIOS through the HP Support Manager.
2. Select the recovery partition (make some backups first through the media creation option).
3. Defrag the hard disk. Very important!
4. Shrink the hard drive within Windows.
5. Download the 10.04 LTS distro.
6. Download the universal USB creator from the Ubuntu site.
7. Create a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu.
8. Set your BIOS to boot from USB, plug your network cable into the router, and start the installation.
9. When the installation finishes, reboot and update the system.
10. Reboot.
11. Go into hardware drivers and do a search (the first time my laptop didn't find the wireless drivers; after I searched for hardware drivers I found them and activated them).
12. Reboot.
13. And everything works for me except the 3D graphics.

So far, it's been working smoothly.